# Get stuck in Login/Register with FirebaseAuth in Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, mobile, firebase-authentication, mobile-development

Recently, I am trying to test Login/Register with FirebaseAuth in Flutter but sometimes when I click the Register/Login button it doesn't do anything but sometimes it succeeds. When I use "run with debugging" in vscode it worked it always succeeds but when I try using "run without debugging" it happened as I said. How could I fix that?

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import "firebase_options.dart";
import "package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart";
import "package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart";
import "package:mynotes/views/login.dart";

void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    title: 'Flutter Demo',
    theme: ThemeData(
      colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.blue),
      useMaterial3: true,
    ),
    home: const RegisterView(),
  ));
}

class RegisterView extends StatefulWidget {
  const RegisterView({super.key});

  @override
  State<RegisterView> createState() => _RegisterViewState();
}

class _RegisterViewState extends State<RegisterView> {
  late final TextEditingController _email;
  late final TextEditingController _password;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _email = TextEditingController();
    _password = TextEditingController();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _email.dispose();
    _password.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("Register"),
        foregroundColor: Colors.white,
        backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
      ),
      body: FutureBuilder(
        future: Firebase.initializeApp(
            options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<FirebaseApp> snapshot) {
          switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
            case ConnectionState.none:
              break;
            case ConnectionState.waiting:
              break;
            case ConnectionState.active:
              break;
            case ConnectionState.done:
              return Column(
                children: [
                  TextField(
                    controller: _email,
                    enableSuggestions: false,
                    autocorrect: false,
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                    decoration: const InputDecoration(
                        hintText: "Enter your email here"),
                  ),
                  TextField(
                    controller: _password,
                    obscureText: true,
                    enableSuggestions: false,
                    autocorrect: false,
                    decoration: const InputDecoration(
                        hintText: "Enter your password here"),
                  ),
                  TextButton(
                    onPressed: () async {
                      final String email = _email.text;
                      final String password = _password.text;

                      try {
                        final UserCredential userCredential = await FirebaseAuth
                            .instance
                            .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
                                email: email, password: password);

                        print(userCredential);
                      } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
                        if (e.code == "weak-password") {
                          print("Weak password");
                        } else if (e.code == "email-already-in-use") {
                          print("Email already exists");
                        } else if (e.code == "invalid-email") {
                          print("Invalid email");
                        }
                      }
                    },
                    child: const Text("Register"),
                  ),
                ],
              );
          }

          return const Text("Loading...");
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

```
I/FirebaseAuth(19153): Creating user with example@gmail.com with empty reCAPTCHA token
I/FirebaseAuth(19153): Creating user with example@gmail.com with empty reCAPTCHA token
I/FirebaseAuth(19153): Creating user with example@gmail.com with empty reCAPTCHA token
E/RecaptchaCallWrapper(19153): Initial task failed for action RecaptchaAction(action=signUpPassword)with exception - The email address is already in use by another account.
I/flutter (19153): Email already exists
```

I want it can succeed everytime I click Register/Login button. Thank you for your helping, guys.

Comment: Can you please add your code?

Comment: @SamiKanafani Okay, I just added the code

Comment: The error message says "The email address is already in use by another account.", so it sounds like you already have a user with that email address in the project - and the project is set to allow only one user account per email address.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thank you for your anwser. But the problem I want to say that I got stuck when clicking to Register/Login button, not the problem that email already exists.

Comment: From what I can see in your code, once the button is pressed, the `UserCredential` gets created. There's no code after that for do anything, e.g. navigating to login screen. Of course its stuck.

Answer (score 0):

I think I know what the problem is. If you try to use print() then it will get stuck sometimes and do not print anything. But if you try using log() from pre-packaged 'dart:developer' then it will always log for you.